# How to modify Observable values with rxjs operators?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular app and in one of the components I'm getting user's notifications(Emails) via a service. the service returns an array of Objects and in each object there's information of an email like subject , userid of the sender, etc.
the structure of array of email object is like this:

```
[{
  UserId:"...",

  Notification:{
     Subject:null,
     Body:"<div>...</div>",
     .
     .
     .
  },
  .
  .
  .
},
.
.
.]
```

some emails don't have subject and the value of `Subject` property is `null` in the object. I want to set a value for emails with `Subject:null`.

```
this.notifService.getAllNotificationsForCurrentUser(userId)
.pipe(
    map(emails => {
       emails.map(email=>{
         if(email.Notification.Subject === null){
            email.Notification.Subject = "(No Subject)";
         }
       })
    }
)
.subscribe(
    result=> this.messages = result
);
```

I used `map` operator and it doesn't work. and it has some errors:

```
Cannot read property 'Notification' of undefined
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: hi, could you please tell in detail again? what is your exact problem?

Comment: If you tried something and it didn't work, then post what you tried, tell precisely what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [rxjs map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

1. The first `map` allows you to modify the array of emails as if flows down the stream. It maps over the stream elements, **each element is an array of emails**.
2. The second `map` changes the array of emails to set the empty `subject` fields to `no subject`. It maps over the emails array, **each element is an email**.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.notifService.getAllNotificationsForCurrentUser(userId).pipe(
    map(emails => {
        return emails.map(email => ({
            ...email,
            Notification: {
                ...Notification,
                Subject: email.subject ? email.subject : 'no subject'
            }
        }));
    })
).subscribe(
    result=> this.messages = result
);
```

Comment: @Nastaran Heydari, you have to return the result from the inner map, in my example I am using an implicit return. Also your inner map does not return anything, use forEach in that case

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for display purposes, you should just do

```
{{email.Notification.Subject || '(No Subject)'}}
```

If not, go for mapping the array.